# multipathd not working after restarting

Tags: centos6, daemon, startup, multipath

Multipathd is not working on CentOS 6.5 x86_64:

```
    device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-87.el6.x86_64
    device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-87.el6.x86_64
```

I'm getting below error while restarting multipathd service:

```
    ux_socket_connect: Connection refused
    Stopping multipathd daemon:                                [FAILED]
    Starting multipathd daemon:                                [  OK  ]
    [root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/multipathd start
    Starting multipathd daemon:                                [  OK  ]
    [root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/multipathd status
    multipathd dead but pid file exists
```

Content of /etc/multipath.conf:

```
            udev_dir                /dev
            polling_interval        10
            path_selector           "round-robin 0"
            path_grouping_policy    multibus
            getuid_callout          "/lib/udev/scsi_id --replace-whitespace --whitelisted --device=/dev/%n"
            prio                    const
            path_checker            readsector0
            rr_min_io               100
            max_fds                 8192
            rr_weight               priorities
            failback                immediate
            no_path_retry           fail
            user_friendly_names     no
    }
    
    blacklist {
    #       wwid 26353900f02796769
            devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
    #       devnode "^hd[a-z]"
            devnode "/dev/sda"
    }
```

Comment: Are there anything interesting in log files?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine also I was hitting same issue

```
# /etc/init.d/multipathd start
Starting multipathd daemon: [ OK ]

# /etc/init.d/multipathd status
multipathd dead but pid file exists
```

Actualy there were two issues

1. `dm_round_robin` kernel module was not loaded 

2. `device-mapper` and `glibc` packages were old , they were not compatible with `multipath` package

Resolution 

1. `/etc/init.d/multipathd stop`

2. `rm /var/run/multipat*`

3. `/sbin/modprob -i  dm_round_robin`

4. `yum update device-mapper`  `yum update glibc`